# Lilypond snippet for a separate coda

Tags: lilypond

I'm hoping to Lilypond something not at all uncommon in pop sheet music but missing from the [snippet repository](http://lsr.dsi.unimi.it/LSR/Search?q=coda) and eluding my search phrases. It's basically an inline block of coda set apart from the bars preceding it. (My attempts at the code are not match for an uploaded [visual example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdr5Y.jpg).)

I'm guessing the ingredients are 'ragged-right', some whitespace, and a separate score {} block for the coda music itself, but is there a way to end one system and start another without a line break? (Hard to think this hasn't been done before—and even more so to imagine it couldn't be done.)

**Update** (March 8, 2012): I've [gotten close](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WhAY2.jpg) to what I want, with the following:

```
\stopStaff s1 \startStaff \bar ""
\mark \markup { \musicglyph #"scripts.coda" }

\override Score.Clef #'space-alist = #'(
    (cue-clef extra-space . 2.0)
    (staff-bar extra-space . 0.0)
    (key-cancellation minimum-space . 3.5)
    (key-signature minimum-space . 3.5)
    (time-signature minimum-space . 4.2)
    (first-note minimum-fixed-space . 5.0)
    (next-note extra-space . 1.0)
    (right-edge extra-space . 0.5)
)

\override Staff.Clef #'full-size-change = ##t
\set Staff.forceClef = ##t
\clef "treble_8"
\key \default
```

The only thing missing from the coda is the systemStartBracket. Can anyone figure out how to insert one in the middle of a system?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'd try a different approach: use a simultaneous staff as described in http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.14/Documentation/notation/modifying-single-staves#ossia-staves and vertically align it to the terminated staff.